# HtmlElement get table with specific ID using C#

Tags: c#, htmlelements

I have simple code which can read html and write data from table:

```
        foreach (HtmlElement hrel in testWebBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table"))
        {
                HtmlElementCollection coll2 = hrel.GetElementsByTagName("tr");
                Console.WriteLine(coll2[0].InnerText);
                Console.WriteLine(coll2[1].InnerText);
                Console.WriteLine(coll2[2].InnerText);
                Console.WriteLine(coll2[3].InnerText);                
        }
```

But I want read table by `id`... How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [`GetElementById`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid(v=vs.110).aspx)?

```
HtmlElement table =  testWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("TableID");
if (table != null)
{
    foreach (HtmlElement row in table.GetElementsByTagName("TR"))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, yes, but no with `var` variable. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @g3278739: i have removed the `var` since it's better to be explicit once you know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GetElementsById](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid(v=vs.110).aspx) to get HTML elements by their id.

```
var table =  testWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("TableID");
```

Comment: I doesn't work for `foreach` error is :  `missing getenumerator`.